# SQL UPDATE and IF statements

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to wrap my head around using an IF statement within an UPDATE query.

I've got this code:

```
UPDATE privatethreads SET to_read = CASE WHEN to_user = 1 THEN '1' ELSE to_read
```

Which will not execute. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong as i've been looking at every other thread relevant to this and phpmyadmin only tells me I have an issue after the end of the statement.

Comment: Do you want to update the value of to_read to '1' when to_user=1 and not to update in other cases?

Comment: @Guneli -- I'm going to add another case to this... or at least I was going to, I think I may have been over thinking this now.. 

I need to have the query update two different columns (to_read and from_read)... I was going to use cases to do so, but I'm starting to think I'm over thinking it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, what you want can be achieved in a more easy way:

```
UPDATE privatethreads SET to_read ='1' WHERE to_user = 1;
```

Comment: Yah.. I think I do... I was so dead set on thinking that this was what I wanted to do (the cases) but Now i'm realizing I could do this simplier... I've had too much caffeine today, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add END at the end of query

```
UPDATE privatethreads SET to_read = CASE WHEN to_user = 1 THEN '1' END
```

Comment: This query update to_read to 1 when to_user=1 in other case to_read do not update